# Если возможность поменять ссылку?

Tags: python, flask, веб-сервер

Во время запуска сайта на локальном сервере Flask нам выдаёт ссылку
http://127.0.0.1:5000
Существует ли способ поменять эту ссылку на локальном сервере например на http://localsite.com?

Comment: В настройках системы измените настройки резолвинга доменных имён так, чтобы нужный вам домен вёл на нужный вам ip-адрес, и запускайте веб-сервер на порту 80

Comment: Можно поподробнее и более простым языком,а то я в этом не сильно разбираюсь